# Read/Write Excel files Visual Studio 2017

Tags: excel, vb.net

I just installed Microsoft Office 2010 (I'm guessing this has some references the program needs), and I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017, what reference do I need to add to write and read .xslx files?

Edit:
The Microsoft Excel 14.0 reference just appeared on the COM list, but I still can't make a file. I'm guessing I need to import something now?

Comment: Possibly you are missing the search terms "COM" and "Interop" whilst performing your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you actually got the reference added as you state.

So then add this at the top of the code window

Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

and this in your code:

```
Dim objApp As New Excel.Application
objApp.Visible = True
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/302094/how-to-automate-excel-from-visual-basic--net-to-fill-or-to-obtain-data

Comment: I was missing the 'Interop' line. Somehow it never showed on my web searches. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using vb.net (Visual Studio 15) and have MS Office 16, and when I added the COM reference Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library to my project, it didn't take. I actually had to browse (in the add reference window) to the following location an add a dll:

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\microsoft.office.interop.excel\15.0.0.0_71be9bcellle9429c\microsoft.office.interop.excel.dll